# Creating a registration form using Stateless Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Can someone show me sample code/explanation on how to build a form using stateless components?

I also couldn't find a Material UI form example using refs.

Note: I am using Material UI components.

Here is my current create form:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
        name: '',
        school: '',
      };
 }


  /*in order to access state from within function, I had to bind this when I made
  the call to submitCandidate i.e. onClick={this.submitCandidate.bind(this)}
  */
  submitCandidate(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //assign the form fields to candidates object
    var newCandidate = {
      name: this.state.name,
      school: this.state.school,
      date: this.state.date
    }
    //inserts candidates object to database
    Candidates.insert(newCandidate);

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(lightBaseTheme)}>
        <div>
        <TextField
          hintText={"Enter Your Name"}
          floatingLabelText={"Name"}
          value={this.state.name}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
        />
        <TextField
          hintText={"Enter Your School"}
          floatingLabelText={"School"}
          value={this.state.school}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ school: e.target.value })}
        />

        <RaisedButton type="submit" label="Submit" onClick={this.submitCandidate.bind(this)} />

          </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of relying on the `onChange` handler, you could use a `ref` on your inputs and when submitting gather all the values up at once - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Comment: @Deryck unfortunately stateless functions don't support refs

Answer (score 1):

Stateless component means that it can't store the state. So your state needs to be stored somewhere else. Preferred state store is Redux nowadays.

Not sure if you are familiar with Redux. If not I recommend to watch [insanely famous Dan Abramov's (Redux creator) Egghead.io series](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux).

If you become familiar how Redux is implementing FLUX pattern, you can place your state (`name` and `school`) into Redux store. This state will be updated by Redux actions. These functions will be passed into your component via `props` as well as updates to the state.

**EDIT 2017-05:**

We started using library called [`redux-form`](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) for handling forms in React+Redux application. It eliminated a lot of boillerplate, is very testable. So I would definitely recommend using it.